# Every locally integrable function defines a Radon measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have just started with Measure Theory and I have read several times that

> Every locally integrable function defines a Radon measure.

I understand this statement in the sense that if we have $f\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ (respecto to Lebesgue measure) , then $\mu(E)=\int_{E}f(x)dx$ (where the integral is respect to Lbesgue measure) defines a Radon measure. **Is this right? How could I prove it?
Is there any measure which is not of this form?**

Maybe these questions are trivial, but I am a little lost.
Thanks.

Edit: After see the answer of @JustDroppedIn I was wondering what happens if $f$ is not non-negative.  I thought that in this case we would obtain a signed measure. However, if $f$ we descompose $f=f^+-f^-$, where $f^+=\frac{f+|f|}{2}\geq{0}$ and $f^-=\frac{f-|f|}{2}\geq{0}$, then $\mu(E)=\int_E f=\int_E f^+-\int_E f^- $ and, by the answer of @JustDroppedIn, $\mu$ is the difference of two positive Radon measures. The problem is that this difference doesn't have to bee a signed measure so **I would like to know what extra hypothesis we neeed above $f$ to obtain a signed Radon measure**.

Comment: Have you tried checking the definition of a Radon measure?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. But I don't know how to start

Comment: What are the requirements for a measure to be Radon?

Comment: The delta measure at $0$ defined by $\delta (A)=1$ if $0 \in A$ and $0$ if $0 \notin A$ is a measure which is not of this form for any $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's recall: a Radon measure is a measure $\mu:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^N)\to[0,\infty]$ such that $\mu$ is regular and $\mu$ is locally finite. Suppose that $f\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and that $f\geq0$. Define $\mu(E)=\int_Ef$. This is a measure and the fact that $f\in L^1_{loc}$ shows immediately that $\mu$ is locally finite. Regularity of $\mu$ follows directly from the regularity of the Lebesgue measure and an application of the well-known convergence theorems.

Comment: Can we extend this result to signed measures, that is $\mu:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^N)\to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @mathlife I believe yes. You just have to be careful that $\mu$ omits either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: .@JustDroppedIn Hello, I was reading your answer again and I was wondering why we must omit the case $\pm \infty$ when $\mu$ is signed but we don't have that omit  the case $\infty$ when $\mu$ is a positive meausre

Comment: @mathlife It is by the definition of signed measures. A signed measure by definition must NOT attain both values $\pm\infty$. There is no such restriction on positive measures of course. If you want, we can discuss on *why* signed measures are defined in this way, but this is another topic. You can check Folland's text. It is the best thing when it comes to measure theory.

Comment: .@JustDroppedIn 
 For example  in Definition 4.1.1 of this text
http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~beforres/PMath451/Course_Notes/Chapter4.pdf there is not such restriction about values $\pm \infty$. Essentially my new question can be reformulated as: What happens if $f$ is not a positive function?

Comment: @mathlife Of course there is: condition 1 is exactly what I am saying

Comment: .@JustDroppedIn Sorry, you are right. But can we say if $f$ is not a non-negative function?

Comment: I added an edit to explain my doubt.